# Install AWX (OSS version of Tower) through Katello

Tags: katello, ansible-tower

I want to install AWX for testing purposes in our organization. I would like to use the Katello server we already have deployed and we use daily. Is there any guideline about it? 
The "official" site was the installation instructions for manual deployment with git replication etc but it will not work for my case since I don't have Internet Access from the specific network I will use and the security policy does not allow us to use proxy servers etc.

Answer (score 0):

[The AWX install document](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/INSTALL.md) also describes official containers to deploy.

Per [the RPM issue](https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/419), they are not interested in official RPMs. Which links to [community created RPMs targeting EL7 that exist.](https://github.com/MrMEEE/awx-build/blob/master/installguide.md)

If RPM deployment does not work, you can download the sources on a different machine and transfer them over in some way. Git can clone from local disk, for example.

Comment: This it not my question. I am not asking for the containers, but for the repo. Step No1 in the documentation is to clone the repo. This is what I cannot do. What I would like is an (official) prebuild container that I could install in the  Katello and use katello as docker registry.